# Pegar parâmetro da URL

Tags: php

Estou criando um site que tem validação de cadastro por email. Assim, ao se cadastrar, o usuário recebe um email de boas vindas contendo um link para ativar seu cadastro e só assim consegue acessar seu Painel de Usuário. Assim, ao se cadastrar, no banco de dados a coluna `u_ativo` recebe `N`. Por email ele recebe um link que ao clicar vai para o site:

```
www.nomedosite.com/ativa-cadastro?email=email@teste.com&id=8378472327
```

Ao chamar essa página quando o usuário clica no link do email, preciso setar a coluna `'u_ativo' = 'S'`, pegando os parametros da URL para ver qual é o usuário que está ativando o cadastro. Quanto aos dados, vou criptografar e comparar. Meu problema mesmo é que nao estou conseguindo pegar os parametros da URL, como por exemplo, usando `$id = $_REQUEST['id']`.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de $_REQUEST use $_GET ou $_POST dependendo do tipo de requisição.